# Detecting HP 7400 scanner (avision detection?)

Tags: scanner, sane

I am having a hard time with detection of my HP 7400 scanner.

"lsusb" says:

```
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 03f0:4311 Hewlett-Packard OfficeJet 7400 series
```

/etc/sane.d/avision.conf has been edited to include:

```
usb 03f0 4311
```

with `SANE_DEBUG_AVISION=255 set, "scanimage -L"` says:

```
[avision] sane_reload_devices: parsing config line "usb 03f0 4311"
[avision] sane_reload_devices: config file line 24: trying to attach
USB:`usb 03f0 4311'
```

[...]

No scanners were identified. If you were expecting something different,
check that the scanner is plugged in, turned on and detected by the
sane-find-scanner tool (if appropriate). Please read the documentation
which came with this software (README, FAQ, manpages).
[avision] sane_exit:

How do I get sane to see this scanner?

- Jon

Answer (score 4):

Try adding :

```
usb 0x03f0 0x4311
```

in `/etc/sane.d/avision.conf`
I did it and it works for my HP 7400C scanner.