# HP Scanjet 8300 Scanner not working on Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (Bionic Beaver)

Tags: scanner

[image]

**scanimage -L can see it:**  Error my backend :    out of memory
device `avision:libusb:002:004' is a Hewlett-Packard ScanJet 8200 flatbed scanner

**simplescan reports** "Unable to connect to scanner." Tried a variety of USB cables.

Please help....

Comment: Check the method from https://askubuntu.com/q/808300/66509 .

Comment: Thank You work fine .....